# Performing a calculation on every item in a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Have a large pandas DataFrame of 1m rows. I want to perform a calculation on every item and create a new DataFrame from it.

The way I'm currently doing it is crazily slow. Any thoughts on how I might improve the efficiency?

```
    # Create some random data in a DataFrame
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    dfData = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(100, 10)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))


    # Key values
    colTotals = dfData.sum(axis=0)
    rowTotals = dfData.sum(axis=1)
    total = dfData.values.sum()

    dfIdx = pd.DataFrame()

    for respId, row in dfData.iterrows():
        for scores in row.iteritems():

            colId = scores[0]
            score = scores[1]

            # Do the calculation
            idx = (score / colTotals[colId]) * (total / rowTotals[respId]) * 100

            dfIdx.loc[respId, colId] = idx
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data. Most likely the `iterrows` is not required.

Comment: @HenryYik - Thanks. Added some random data to give an idea of the shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the logic of your code

`dfData.div(colTotals).mul((total / rowTotals) * 100, 0)`

Comment: Too easy. Thank you so much. That run extremely fast!!